# Excel VBA - If number of rows contain text then enter specific text in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to work out how to count number of cells that have text in them and then depending on the total number of cells that have text, paste certain text in other cells.

i.e If cell A1:A3 contain text, then enter "3x1" in cell B1 and enter "3x2" in cell B2.

likewise, If cell A1:A4 contain text, then enter "4x1" in cell B1 and enter "4x2" in cell B2.

UPDATE1:

Let me try to give another example since numbers confuses people when it comes to coding :) IF cells A1:A3 have text, count it and then depending on how many number of cells have text, enter below in B2 and B3 2 cells with text = "Three" in B2 and text "Four" in B3 3 cells with text = "Five" in B2 and text "Six" in B3

Including above, i would like to add one more thing which is to ignore any cell and dont include it in the count if it has, lets say digits 242

Comment: Struggling to understand the logic to the convention of 3x1,3x2.  Where does the 2 come from?  Second row? Just so we understand exactly what it is you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the solution for your requirement

```
Sub test1()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With


ws.Range("B1").Value = """" & LastRow & "X1"""
ws.Range("B2").Value = """" & LastRow & "X2"""


End Sub
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the step where you count merely the cells containing text? So, you need to exclude any possible cells containing a formula, a number, or being blank (between non-empty cells). No? But maybe I just didn't understand the question correctly.

Comment: many thanks newjenn although as Ralph pointed out, it does need to check for text in the cell, not just count rows. Secondly, i tried to enter your code anyways but when i run it, why am i getting digits "20 before X1/X2" for some reason. can you make it so it enters specific text not just calculated text

Answer (score 0):

Example like this.

```
Sub Testing()

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`


For i = 1 to LastRow
If Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(j, i) = "Pass" Then
  Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(k, i).Value = "Pass"

End If
Next i
```